# VueJS - Share global variable from data to internal scss file (DYNAMIC CSS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, babeljs

I have a master component named `App.vue` and in that file I am calling an ajax request to the server which returns JSON of colors.

My ajax call is located inside of the vue life cycle hook named `created`. When the ajax is done, it will populate the local data base on the result.

In the same file, I have style written in SCSS.

```html
<style lang="scss">
$primary: #ff2000;
$secondary: #000111;
</style>
```

Is it possible to share to this SCSS file block those JSON of colors from the state of the components? Please imagine the below image attached.

[image]

** **CORRECTIONS** **

1. this.colors = colors.data
2. .color-secondary { background: $secondary; }

The colors are dynamic that is why it is coming from a database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I think I nailed it!! But I'm not quite sure if it is recommended or not. I don't even know yet the up and down side of doing this tweak. But it did work! :)

```js
created() {
  // assume that this colors are coming from an async ajax call
  let colors = {
    primary: 'red',
    secondary: 'blue'
  }

  this.setThemeColors(colors);
},
methods: {
  setThemeColors(colors) {
    let style = document.documentElement.style;

    for (let key of Object.keys(colors)) {
      style.setProperty("--theme-color-" + key, colors[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

It's all set up from the root of your stylesheet. Check below to use it,

```css
<style lang="scss">
$color-primary: var(--theme-color-primary);
$color-secondary: var(--theme-color-secondary);

.color-primary {
  color: var(--theme-color-primary)
}
.color-secondary {
  color: var(--theme-color-secondary)
}
</style>
```

But another problem encountered, css variables is not working in IE11 and below!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update the values of SCSS variables dynamically like you want to. Web browsers do not understand SCSS, only CSS. SCSS is compiled into CSS ahead of time; the variables get compiled away.

Somewhat recently, [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) have become a thing, so maybe that could be something that you can consider looking into.

Other than that, you don't generally make dynamic updates to stylesheets. Perhaps some kind of [CSS-in-JS](https://cssinjs.org/) solution might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The key feature of SCSS is that it compiles readable / less bloated CSS into normal CSS. 
Adjusting the styles on-the-fly inside a single file component is not possible.

See this question for possible workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48201646/6803592

If you're looking for a solution, you could possibly get the colors **before** your vue app loads.